# How can I get USDT/USDC for Polygon Mumbai Testnet?

Tags: testnets, polygon, faucets, usdt, usdc

I am working on a DeFi application on Polygon (Mumbai Testnet), and want to integrate stablecoins like USDT or USDC.
I have looked for a faucet of USDT and USDC, and found none of them on **POLYGON MUBAI TESTNET**.

Is there any particular for that?
If not is there any work around for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've gotten some assets for polygon mumbai here: https://faucet.paradigm.xyz/

Including DAI/wETH/MATIC.

Should be able to trade those for USDC/USDT. From a quick search, can trade for USDT on Mumbai here:
https://quickswap.exchange/#/swap

I tested it, and was able to swap MATIC & wMATIC for USDT.

I tried adding a little liquidity to / creating a (mumbai) MATIC <-> USDC pool for you. You have to put in the Matic USDC token manually to see that pair, that token address is here: 0xe11A86849d99F524cAC3E7A0Ec1241828e332C62

(There's only 5 MATIC/5USDC in that pool, so only suitable for small amounts.)

This faucet also gives out USDC directly: https://calibration-faucet.filswan.com/#/dashboard

instructions: https://docs.filswan.com/development-resource/swan-token-contract/acquire-testnet-usdc-and-matic-tokens

Comment: Thanks for the response. The direct faucet is not working. And how can I trade USDC using the first wallet please let me know.

Comment: The direct faucet worked for me right when I posted this--I tested it and received USDC. Weird.

Comment: added link to a swap on mumbai for MATIC to USDT.

Comment: Just got USDC from that faucet again, btw. First time I tried today I got an error, but then 20 minutes later I tried again and it worked. YMMV.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Yes it's working for me also now. Thanks again.

Comment: Note that the https://faucet.paradigm.xyz site gives `0x9c3C9283D3e44854697Cd22D3Faa240Cfb032889` as the address for wETH on Mumbai, but that's in fact the address for wMATIC. So your 0.1 drip won't go nearly as far as with wETH.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I found so far is (that still works):

1. Create a developers account on Circle ([here](https://developers.circle.com/docs/circle-payments-api-quickstart)) and get an API key
2. Use their demo app to add balance to your account available [here](https://developers.circle.com/docs/circle-payments-api-quickstart) or use their example that is deployed online [here](https://sample-sandbox.circle.com/). Inside the app, first add your API key, second add a credit card (they have a prefill button) and third charge it.
3. Go to your [dashboard](https://my-sandbox.circle.com/account) for Circle developers and transfer out your funds to a Ethereum wallet (by default they will transfer them to the test network Goerli)
4. Go to the PoS [Polygon Bridge](https://wallet-dev.polygon.technology/bridge/) that allows you bridge your USDC from Goerli to Mumbai
5. Enjoy your test USDC in Polygon Mumbai

Answer (score 1):

Use https://www.buildbear.io/ You can fork Ethereum, Polygon, Binance, Optimism, Arbitrum, Fantom, and Avalanche chains, allowing you to test your projects on the actual Mainnet state.

Answer (score 0):

If you work on test-net's my solution for problem with broken faucets was to deploy MockERC20 contract and to use them while I'm testing things. Basically no need for USDC faucet at all. Then ones you go to production just substitute addresses, double check math and decimals places and you are ready to go....

Answer (score 0):

As another comment states, I would suggest using the [Foundry](https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry) EVM development tool.

Then, in your development and testing:

1. Fork mumbai with an infura RPC
2. Give your wallets any ERC20 you need to test with the `deal` cheatcode

By forking mumbai mainet, the tests will run the exact same as if they were actually on mainnet.

Answer (score 0):

The best faucet I got for USDC after so long is https://usdcfaucet.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here, easy to use, and has too many tokens.
Hope it's helps

https://faucet.dsolutions.mn/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).